# Spring MVC default Authentication How to add a user / registration

Tags: java, spring, authentication, registration, access-control

When I include spring-boot-starter-security in my project, it automatically creates a new database Table "users" which leads me to believe that it would automatically authenticate against entries in that table when trying to login on the login-page (which is correctly displayed under "/login")

My question is how I can add new users into this table -> what password encryption is used by default, or do I need to change it? Is there maybe a default registration page I can activate and then customize? Or do I need to write my own Login-Verification and then customize my registration to it?

Since the Login-Authentication seems to be already coming with the package I was hoping I could simply write a method to add users but I can't find information on how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think spring-boot automatically create new `users` table in your database. It is the default `UserDetailsService` which as a single user with username `user` and random password. You can modify it in `application.properties` file (I supposed you are using .proprites):

```
spring.security.user.name
spring.security.user.password
```

I do not think you will do this in production when you application can have multiple users.

For more detail and to implement your worn UserDetailsService, please check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security)

Comment: Ah I just realized that my mistake might have been that I created an Entity-Class User with TableName users that probably already created the database (since I added it at the same time as the security configuration I missunderstood why it was created)

Thanks a lot!